# Remove duplicates from two lists

Tags: java, lambda, collections

I have two lists of Strings and am removing duplicates like this:

```
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4");
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("1", "4", "5", "6");
List<String> duplicates = list1.stream().filter(s -> list2.contains(s)).collect(Collectors.toList());
list1.removeAll(duplicates);
list2.removeAll(duplicates);
```

So the result is:

```
list1 = 2, 3
list2 = 5, 6
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this? i.e. with fewer statements.

Comment: *Better* in what way? Less comparisons, less memory consumption?

Comment: Define "better".  If you mean "asymptotic time complexity", then you can do better via HashSets.

Comment: "Better" can be opinionated. Be careful what you ask.

Comment: Do you want to remove duplicates, as in having only unique items, or do you want the difference of the two sets? You are now removing all items that appear in both lists. For the former, just use a Set. For the latter, this looks ok.

Comment: Removing items that appear in both lists. Thanks @OliverCharlesworth for the tip to use HashSet

Answer (score 1):

You can use `removeAll` which is defined in `Collection` interface.

> boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c)
>
> Removes all of this collection's elements that are also contained in
> the specified collection (optional operation). After this call
> returns, this collection will contain no elements in common with the
> specified collection.

```
// init
List<String> sourceList1 = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4");
List<String> sourceList2 = Arrays.asList("1", "4", "5", "6");

// you need to create duplicate collection, because removeAll modify collection 
List<String> resultList1 = new ArrayList(sourceList1);
List<String> resultList2 = new ArrayList(sourceList2);

//remove duplicates from collections
resultList1.removeAll(sourceList2); // second from first
resultList2.removeAll(sourceList1); // first from second
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possibilities worth considering is to create `Set<String>` and add these lists to it. Set allows adding only unique values to itself, it prevents adding duplicates.

The first way to use `Set`: Create a `Set` containing an intersection of both lists. Adding to new, getting rid of duplicates lists is taking place only if you checked that every object of the source is not present in previously created `Set` of duplicates.

Second way (only if your lists doesn't care about holding duplicates itself - for example in the first you have two times the same value existing): Create a `Set` for the first and for the second list, and add these lists to them and after that check for duplicates.

As I mentioned in comments I could misunderstood question and looked for "another", not for "more efficient" way of achieving what you're asking for, but maybe it could actually be helpful nonetheless.

Comment: Please explain how that would work in this case. OP wants to remove duplicates completely, not have *at most* one value of each.

Comment: I could misunderstand a bit and this wouldn&#39;t be the most efficient way to a achieve it, so I&#39;m sorry for missing the part of providing &quot;the more efficient way&quot;. First and second list could check the common part with this set and store the result in new list. Again, I'm sorry, I misunderstood it and wanted to provide another way, not the most efficient one.

Comment: I am not talking about the *efficient* part. I do not see how you would use `Set`s at all in trying to remove the duplicated values from both arrays.

Comment: @luk2302 - Converting from lists to sets would reduce the expected runtime (for the intersection logic) from O(n^2) to O(n).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I see, using `Set`s from the beginning on through would work, yes.

Comment: I updated my answer to let you know what I meant writing about Sets.